Unable to read a PDF from NAS (network file share) on windows
We were trying to write Junit test cases for our code that uses AEM packages for Assembler service, Output service and PDF generator Service. Our code tries to calculate the number of pages in a PDF document that has been passed to it. This PDF document is of type "com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document". In real time, this document is picked up from NAS drive based on the form ID passed to this method. However, since we are writing and executing test cases on local IDE, we tried hardcoding the NAS path to "//nasservername/aem_forms/DEV/Input_Output_Files_UnitTestCases/APP11111.pdf" this started throwing the below error
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:////nasservername/aem_forms/DEV/Input_Output_Files_UnitTestCases/APP11111.pdf 

I am not sure, how can i simply pick up the PDF document from NAS share and run it through my code. Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated. Below is a snippet of my method
@Test
public void getTotalPages() throws 
     IOException,
     ParserConfigurationException,
     SAXException,
     TransformerException
{
    String path = "//nasservername/aem_forms/DEV/Input_Output_Files_UnitTestCases/APP11111.pdf";
    org.w3c.dom.Document document = FileSystemUtils.getDocFromFileSystem(path);
       
    /** Here I am converting org.w3c.dom.Document to 
        com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document **/
   com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document pdfFile =
        ConversionUtils.convertDomToAEMFD(document); 
   Integer expcount = 18;
   Integer pgcount = null;
   pgcount = Integer.valueOf(
        AssemblerHelperService.GetTotalPages(asm, pdfFile)
   );
   assertEquals(expcount, pgcount);
}

Tried hardcoding the NAS path, tried importing the PDF into IDE nothing seemed to work. I need this PDF to be of type adobeFD document so my code can parse it. If it is not an adobeFD document and I try converting it, I get the below error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/adobe/aemfd/docmanager/source/DocumentSourceHandler


Commenting to seek help. We still havent figured out a way to read a PDF from NAS to execute our JUNIT test cases. We need this PDF to be of type "com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document"
